Focus eldoc-doc-buffer buffers default
Is there a way for eldoc-doc-buffer called buffers to focus by default like with the option help-window-select for help buffers?
Or is there a generic way of making buffers attract focus on creation/being made visible?

You can use shackle
(use-package shackle
  :ensure t
  :hook (after-init . shackle-mode)
  :config
  (setq shackle-default-size 0.4
        shackle-rules
        `(("\\*eldoc.*" :align t :select t :regexp t))))


